# I want to prove that the following is a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $p \geq 1, a = (a_{1},a_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^2, b = (b_{1},b_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Denote $d_{p}(a,b) = (|a_{1} - b_{1}|^{p} + |a_{2} - b_{b}|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Prove that $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_{p})$ is a metric space.

Attempt:

Intuitively, $d_{p}(a,b) = d_{p}(b,a)$ and $d_{p}(a,b) = 0 \Rightarrow a = b$ make sense because if you think of $p = 2$, it is just the usual distance formula that we all know about in algebra. Therefore, those conditions seem to make sense to me. As for the triangle inequality, I am not sure how to prove it is true.

Comment: If $ a=b$, then isn't the metric space just $\mathbb {R}^2 $?

Comment: I think so? It seems to make sense.

Comment: $\mathbb {R}^2 $ is a metric space, so the space you've defined is a metric space.

Comment: I would like to prove why the triangle inequality holds true though.

Comment: Take three points $ x, y, z $ and substitute their values, say $(0, 0), (a, 0), (b, c) $ and assign some values to $ a, b, c $. This should then show you if the triangle inequality holds for your metric.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Each of your three comments so far is highly problematic. The first one is absurd, the second one is false (a metric space is not a set but a set AND a metric on it) and the third one is false (one cannot check something is a metric by checking only the triangle inequality for three specific points).

Answer (score 1):

the metric you defined is induced by a norm, the so called $p$-Norm. especially this defines a metric on any $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $p\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{ \infty \} $. the triangle inequality is called "Minkowski inequality" wich is proofed by using the "Hölder inequality".

I found a pdf file online where you can read the proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's not that trivial at all. So a good exercise would be to rewrite the proof for $\mathbb{R^2}$.

here is the link: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~dsim/cs724/norms.pdf

It's chapter 5.2 from the beginning up to Corollary 5.11

EDIT (on your comment):
Sure you can write down it's clear, but if this is a homework for a basic lecture: i would like to see an argument why it's clear to you (if i were supposed to correct your homework).

so $$d_p (a,b) = (|a_1-b_1|^p+|a_2-b_2|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow (|a_1-b_1|^p+|a_2-b_2|^p)=0^p=0\\
\Leftrightarrow |a_1-b_1|=0\text{ and }|a_2-b_2|=0
\\ \Leftrightarrow a=b$$

and the symmetry is really straightforward:

$$d_p (a,b) = (|a_1-b_1|^p+|a_2-b_2|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
= (|b_1-a_1|^p+|b_2-a_2|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} =d_p(b,a)$$

So you see the tricky part is really the triangle inequality.

In homework problems, you have to convince the reader that you understand what you're saying and "it's trivial" is not very convincing ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have a quick question. Would you think the other two properties of a metric space are trivial enough to leave out for this particular example or do you think they need proving as well.

Comment: I suppose you are right. Saying something is trivial is indeed not very convincing. Maybe the term rubbed off on me when I was an undergraduate because that is all my teachers would say because they were extremely intelligent. But whats trivial to them may not be trivial to others :)